# scalaで型パラメータをscalaのクラスで渡してもJavaのクラスになるのはなぜ？

Tags: java, scala

お世話になっております．
scalaの初心者です．以下のコード動作の理由が分からず悩んでいます．

```
scala> case class MyVector[A]() {
  def test(init:A) = {
    println("type=" + init.getClass)
  }
}
scala> (new MyVector[Int]()).test(3)
type=class java.lang.Integer
```

Intを渡したのでIntegerじゃなくてIntになって欲しいのですが．．．

よろしくお願い致します．

Comment: javaのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 3):

JVM の仕組みに拠ります。

まず大前提として JVM では プリミティブ型 を型パラメータに指定できません。
そのため Java では型パラメータとして `int` を指定すると、
コンパイル時に自動的に、`int` に対応する非プリミティブ型である `Integer` に置き換えています。

JVM を用いる Scala においても、この前提は覆せません。
よって例示されたコードにおいて `A` (=`init.getClass`) は `Int` ではなく `Integer` となります。

Comment: `Class型のインスタンス` 自体は存在するような。`classOf[Int]` で取得できたり、`java.lang.Class#isPrimitive` メソッドありますし

Comment: @KenjiYoshida ありがとうございます。指摘を受けたとおりですので、より正確な書き方に修正しました。

Answer (score 2):

Java の仕様では、「**ジェネリクスに使用される型（総称型）は Object クラスを継承していること**」が求められます。よって、ジェネリクス型の変数に、Object クラスを継承していないプリミティブ型のデータを保持することはできません。 Scala の場合は、総称型が Object型なのか プリミティブ型なのかという判断をコンパイル時にしています。

件の `test()` メソッドの場合、Scala のコンパイラは 型A が Object を継承した総称型と見なし、以下のような Java コードとして見なせるバイトコードを生成します。

```
public void test(Object init)
{
    System.out.println(
        (new StringBuilder())
            .append("type=")
            .append(init.getClass())
            .toString());
}
```

`test()` メソッドの引数 `init` の型に注目してください。 `Object` 型ですね。
`Object` 型の入れ物に、 プリミティブ型の `int` 値を入れたならば本来、エラーとなる
ところなのですが、

- `int` <=> `java.lang.Integer`
- `short` <=> `java.lang.Short`
- `float` <=> `java.lang.Float`
- `double` <=> `java.lang.Double`

以上のような型変換が可能な場合、コンパイラは `int` 型を `Integer`型に
相互暗黙変換させるおせっかいなコードを組み込みます。今回は `int` 型の値が `test()` メソッドに引数として渡される直前に `java.lang.Integer` 型の値に自動変換されることになりました。結果、 `getClass()` が、 `java.lang.Integer` を返すことになりました。

補足：

Scala の `Int` は、プリミティブ型 (Java の `int` ) であると対応付けしてしまいがちですが、そうではありません。Scala の `Int` は、最適化のためにコンパイラに特別扱いされて扱いが煩雑になっています。Scala のコンパイラは、`scala.Int` で記述されたものをできるだけJava の `int` 型として扱おうとしますが、やむ終えない場合は、`Integer` としてもあつかえるよう、魔法の/保険のコードを付加したりします。

コンパイラは、大方のところ `int` 及び `java.lang.Integer` を隠す良い仕事しますが、それは完璧ではないことがあります。例えば、今回の例に似た以下のコードをコンパイルしてみてください。（Scala 2.9.3 以前限定。）

```
case class GenericsIntBug[A <: Int]() {
    def test(init:A) = {
          println("type=" + init.getClass)
    }
}
```

すると、コンパイルが通るものの、実行時に必ず例外の発生するメソッドが出来上がります。バイトコードを見ると、このメソッド内部では、プリミティブ型 `int` のデータを扱いながら、そこに存在しないメソッド `getClass()` を呼び出そうとしています。  Java であれは、以下のようなコンパイル不能のコードです。

```
public void test(int init)
{
    System.out.println(
        (new StringBuilder())
            .append("type=")
            .append(init.getClass()).toString());
}
```

面白いので、興味があれば scala.Int を使った処理を一度ディスアセンブルして見ることをお勧めしますよ。
(補足の例の詳細は [このGist](https://gist.github.com/hyamamoto/ad177fe9233536bfc2ec) に張りました)

Comment: この補足で示していただいた挙動は面白いですねぇ。確かにコンパイラがエラーにしてくれたほうが、わかりやすいと感じます。

Comment: `コンパイルが通るものの、絶対に実行できないtest() メソッド`

の例で、言いたいことがよくわからないのですが、普通にInt渡して実行できると思いますよ？

Comment: `プリミティブ型 int のデータを扱いながら、そこに存在しないメソッド getClass()` という記述ですが、JVMレベルでは存在しませんが、Scalaの言語上は、IntにgetClassは存在します https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L437

Comment: コメントを頂き、光栄です。`コンパイルが通るものの、絶対に実行できないtest() メソッド`について。これは、「必ず例外を発生する test() メソッド」で、言い過ぎですね。伝えたかったことは、コンパイル後のデータ型が単純に scala.Int 型ではなくなるということで、この例ではコーダーの期待を裏切るような結果になったということです。それ以上はここで説明しきれないような気がします。

Comment: `プリミティブ型 int のデータを扱いながら、そこに存在しないメソッド getClass() ... 言語上は、IntにgetClassは存在します`について。

はい。存在するからこそ、チェックを通り、コンパイルが完了しますが、コンパイル後のクラスファイルの中での処理は異なっています。整数データをスタックに詰み、`invokevirtual` で `getClass()` を呼び出しているので、型不一致を原因とした一般的でない例外が発生します。これは、Scala のコンパイラが、`boxToInteger`, `anyValClass` の埋め込みを忘れたからではないかと考えました。

私の試した Scala のバージョンが古めなので、現バージョンで直っている可能性はあります。後で手が空いたときに、最新バージョンで試して、大丈夫であれば、どのバグであったのか明記して過去のことであることがわかるように修正します。

Comment: @Kenji これはコンパイラのバグでした。2.10.1 で修正されています。ログをGist にまとめました。 https://gist.github.com/hyamamoto/ad177fe9233536bfc2ec

Comment: なるほど、たしかに(修正済みの)バグですね。ありがとうございます